# Multivariate Variable Length Timeseries in TFRecord dataset

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, tfrecord

I am trying to compose a TFRecord dataset from the UCI repository: https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/Character+Trajectories

The data consists of 2858 samples with each a class and a multivariate (=3) sequence of measurements. Maximum length is 205 steps.

When I create the TFRecord dataset, it seems that a tf.train.SequenceExample is the object to go for. But all the examples cover only univariate timeseries.

```
with tf.python_io.TFRecordWriter('/tmp/test.tfrecord') as writer:
for seq, cls in zip(sequences, classes)):
    LEN = seq.shape[1]
    example = tf.train.SequenceExample()
    example.context.feature["length"].int64_list.value.append(LEN)
    example.context.feature["class"].int64_list.value.append(cls)
    example_tokens = record_seq.feature_lists.feature_list['sequence']
    for i in range(LEN):
        #THIS does not work for 3xLEN sequences
        example_tokens.feature.add().float_list.value.append(seq[:,i])
```

How do I write the 3xLEN sequence to TFrecord using SequenceExample?

Comment: Welcome to SO; please clarify *exactly* what your question is, and provide some code (what you have tried so far) to illustrate the issue.

Comment: added code for more clarity